# std::string as a key in std::map using a compare operator

Tags: c++, key, std, stdstring, stdmap

I'm trying to use a std::string as a key in a std::map however, i'm unable to find() correctly. My code is somewhat complicated and large so this is a small program that demonstrates the problem I'm having. If someone could tell me why this doesn't work, i'd be very grateful.

Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <map>

struct comparer
{
    public:
    bool operator()(const std::string x, const std::string y)
    {
         return x.compare(y)==0;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::map<std::string, int, comparer> numbers;
    numbers.insert(std::pair<std::string,int>("One",1));
    numbers.insert(std::pair<std::string,int>("Two",2));
    numbers.insert(std::pair<std::string,int>("Three",3));
    numbers.insert(std::pair<std::string,int>("Four",4));
    numbers.insert(std::pair<std::string,int>("Five",5));


    std::map<std::string, int, comparer>::iterator it=numbers.find("Three");
    if(it!=numbers.end())
        printf("The number is %d\n",(*it).second);
    else
        printf("Error, the number is not found\n");
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Remove your `comparer` and it will work just fine. The thing is, you didn't implement it properly. It should return `true` if `x` is to be placed *before* `y`. Or change `==0` to `<0` or `>0` (it doesn't really matter).

Comment: I changed the comparer to return x.compare(y)<0; and it worked fine, thank you. Removing the comparer didn't work btw.   #SOLVED.

Comment: You're welcome, but you're sure mistaking about the removal. If you replace all occurences of `std::map<std::string, int, comparer>` with `std::map<std::string, int>` it will sure work.

Comment: The problem I am having in my main application is that I have to check for duplicates in the map before adding a new pair. However, it is not detecting the duplicates properly

Comment: I was talking about this code, not your application, of course. As for duplicates, `map` isn't allowed to have any unlike `multimap`.

Comment: actually this doesn;t seem to be the case, when i add two pairs that have the same key value, iterating through the map shows 2 entries with the same key.

Comment: With your old comparer, you mean?

Answer (score 3):

`comparer::operator()` should return value of operator <, not of operator ==.

Answer (score 3):

`std::map` (and `set` and their `multi` variants) enforce [strict weak ordering](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html).

```
x.compare(y) == 0;
```

Will return true if the strings are *equal*. The comparer should return whether the first string should go before the second string. Either return [`x.compare(y) < 0`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/) or just leave your comparision functor out.

Answer (score 0):

The custom compare operation is not usually required (you can normally just use `std::map<std::string, int>`), but for a bit of optimization when using (not very short) strings as keys and passing a string constant (char* constant) (or `std::string_view` or any other type that can be easily compared to `std::string` without converting to `std::string`) to `contains()` or `find()`, see https://www.cppstories.com/2021/heterogeneous-access-cpp20/.

(Also your `comparer::operator()` could take const string references, to avoid copying there as well: `bool operator()(const std::string& x, const std::string& y) const`...)

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <map>
struct comparer
{
    public:
    bool operator()(const std::string x, const std::string y) const
    {
         return x.compare(y)==0;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::map<std::string, int, comparer> numbers;
    numbers.insert(std::pair<std::string,int>("One",1));
    numbers.insert(std::pair<std::string,int>("Two",2));
    numbers.insert(std::pair<std::string,int>("Three",3));
    numbers.insert(std::pair<std::string,int>("Four",4));
    numbers.insert(std::pair<std::string,int>("Five",5));


    std::map<std::string, int, comparer>::iterator it=numbers.find("Three");
    if(it!=numbers.end())
        printf("The number is %d\n",(*it).second);
    else
        printf("Error, the number is not found\n");
}
```